# Pledges on contact's dashboard

Tags: pledges

I'm using CiviCRM 5.67 with Drupal 7. On the contact's dashboard the "Pledges" tab is missing. On the admin page "Customize data and screen" > "Display preferences" I've checked in the first box to show Pledges, but the tab is not shown up. Where should I set something to show up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your site is using the Contact layout editor extension where you can over-ride the tabs or any custom module or extension that hides the tab

Comment: Thank you, saved my day :) My fault, because if you use Contact Editor with not the default layout, you should enable tabs in this new layout, too. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the CiviPledge component/extension is enabled:

Visit **Administer -> System Settings -> Extensions** and enable CiviPlege.